# Grid system bootstrap not responsive in mobile device and other smaller devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I encounter a problem here where on my desktop everything is fine but when on mobile or any smaller device it's not fully responsive.

[image]

Comment: everything fine in desktop but when i turn the mobile view everything messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding an additional class to the col divs.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 item6">...</div>
```

The class **item6** has an assigned width, in pixels(185px), not to mention margins. If they are all like that, which I assume they are, that will break the responsiveness.  That set pixel width is overriding the responsiveness (which is set accordingly via percentages).

For things to try, first take the item class off the column divs, and create a div inside those that has the item class on it. Then, via CSS media queries, you will have to adjust those widths/styles accordingly. Also, you can look into trying to use Bootstrap's `img-responsive` class to see if that helps your cause.

Comment: what should i do :(

Comment: Thank you so much for that info